# Mono.Cecil unresolved tokens when renaming a generic type's field

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

When I read an assembly and rename a field that's contained inside a generic type, and then write the assembly, all references to this field inside the methods become unresolved tokens. I know that the same also happens to method references if I rename them.

```
// This is a generic class.
TypeDefinition type = GetSomeGenericType();

// This field is referenced from a method in this type.
type.Fields[0].Name = "_anotherName";
assemblyDefinition.Write(...);
```

The resulting assembly won't work. Is this the intended behavior?

I found out that if I go and manually change the instruction's operand to the `FieldDefinition` instead of the `FieldReference` before writing the assembly everything works. But isn't this supposed to be handled automatically by Cecil just like it handles non-generic types?

**EDIT:**

Turns out, when I rename the field, the reference to it from instruction operands will break as the `Resolve()` method returns null then. Still on the lookout for a decent solution for this.