# Get member definition from reference in Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I noticed that the field or method references in certain types of methods (a method in a generic type for example) will be of `FieldReference` type, not `FieldDefinition` although the field (or the method) is in the same module, in the same type. How can I get the `FieldDefinition` from this `FieldReference`?

I tried `module.Import` and `module.MetadataResolver.Resolve` but both don't work.

A follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767780/mono-cecil-unresolved-tokens-when-renaming-a-generic-types-field) question, but a more general one.

**EDIT:**

A simple generic class:

```
public class HelperClass<T>
{
    private int _someInt;

    void SomeMethod(int i)
    {
        _someInt = i;
    }
}
```

`SomeMethod`'s body contains:

```
...
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: ldarg.1
IL_000a: stfdl System.Int32 HelperClass`1<T>::_someInt
....
```

The `IL_000a` opcode's operand is supposed to be a `FieldDefinition` normally, after all it's in the same module. But because `HelperClass` is generic I suppose, the operand is a `FieldReference` that won't resolve, I can just hope to compare the fullnames to actually find the `FieldDefinition`.

In this case this is not big of a problem, but it is when the reference is to other members in other generic types, I'm sure there's a better way to do it than enumerating through all the types to find the definition.

**EDIT:**

The `HelperClass<>` is from a module that is loaded at runtime by `AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly`, that's when the `.Resolve()` returns null instead of returning the `FieldDefinition`.

**UPDATE:**

It turned out that because I'm changing the name of the field in the generic type, the reference is breaking and `Resolve()` is returning null. Still on look for a decent solution for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767780/mono-cecil-unresolved-tokens-when-renaming-a-generic-types-field).

Comment: Does calling Resolve() on the reference not work? (I.e. `var myFieldDefinition = myFieldReference.Resolve();`)

Comment: @rileywhite Nope, returns null. I thought it should be a definition at first, but I think references to members of generic types are handled differently in Cecil.

Comment: Could you post code that reproduces what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

*I've changed the code to separate types into different projects in different solutions. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to reproduce the issue, but I'm willing to keep trying if it will help.*

I'm able to resolve the type reference with the following code. If you are able to provide more details for a reproduction, I'd be willing to take another crack at this :-)

This is the only type in an assembly called TargetLibrary.dll. I compiled it in its own solution, and copied the assembly into `C:\Temp`.

```
public class HelperClass<T>
{
    private int _someInt;

    void SomeMethod(int i)
    {
        _someInt = i;
    }
}
```

This code is in a different assembly, which is compiled into a console exe file within its own solution.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var module = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"C:\Temp\TargetLibrary.dll").MainModule;

        Console.WriteLine("For HelperClass<>");
        var helperClass = module.Types[1];
        var someMethod = helperClass.Methods[0];
        var someMethodBody = someMethod.Body;
        foreach (var instruction in someMethodBody.Instructions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                instruction.Offset,
                instruction.OpCode.Code,
                instruction.Operand == null ? "<null>" : string.Format("{0} / {1}", instruction.Operand.GetType().FullName, instruction.Operand.ToString()));

            var fieldReference = instruction.Operand as FieldReference;
            if (fieldReference != null)
            {
                var fieldDefinition = fieldReference.Resolve();
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "\t\tResolved field reference operand: {0} / {1}",
                    fieldDefinition.GetType().FullName,
                    fieldDefinition.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this produces the following output.

```
For HelperClass<>
0       Ldarg_0 <null>
1       Ldarg_1 <null>
2       Stfld   Mono.Cecil.FieldReference / System.Int32 TargetLibrary.HelperClass`1<T>::_someInt
                Resolved field reference operand: Mono.Cecil.FieldDefinition / System.Int32 TargetLibrary.HelperClass`1::_someInt
7       Ret     <null>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the reference is actually from a loaded module, I'm talking about a module that I loaded at runtime. That's when the Resolve() returns null, your example is working with a generic type from the executing assembly, and I have no idea why this works while the other one doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm...it seems like the assembly resolver associated with the reference may be having problems locating the assembly, which is weird because you used the resolver to load the assembly already. I'll take another go at it when I have a few minutes.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. To make things clearer, I use `AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly` to load the MainModule, and go from there. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @mrahhal, I've updated the code based on your feedback. Is there anything else you can think of that you might be doing differently? I'm using Mono.Cecil version 0.9.5.4 installed from NuGet in Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5, in case that matters.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I found the problem, in my other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767780/mono-cecil-unresolved-tokens-when-renaming-a-generic-types-field) I state that I'm actually changing the names of some of the fields as I go. I found that when I do that, the ".Resolve" method returns null. I've accepted your answer, but do you have a suggestion on how to do that without breaking this reference?
Of course I can think of a solution, but I'd like to look for a simple one before going the other way.